# Managing out of control robot sessions with Redis

Tags: redis, sessions, robots.txt

I've been having major issues with robots leaving sessions files.  Over 100 sessions / second.  At some point Redis just stopped accepting the sessions and Magento went to writing them back to disk.  I have no idea what happened there.  I flushed the DB and it still refused to use Redis.  But that is a problem for another day because I then discovered the session problem.

So I've changed robots to limit crawls every 30 minutes and I blocked the Baiduspider/2.0 user agent to no avail.

I created a CRON job to search the session files every 15 minutes because I still want legitimate sessions to exist for a week.

grep -lrIZ Baiduspider/2.0; /var/session/* | xargs -0 rm -f --

So my question is there anything better / cleaner to handle this.  Followup is there a command for Redis that will do the same thing I'm doing with CRON and the file system

Comment: Honestly since this is more around bots/spiders and Redis than Magento: http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-limit-the-crawl-rate-of-bots-in-a-website & https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29883/need-to-stop-bots-from-killing-my-webserver

Comment: I've already made changes like these.  It's not reducing the amount of bot session files.  In addition I'm still looking for a solution for removing sessions of bots from Redis while leaving legitimate sessions.

Comment: How do you currently have Redis configured in your `local.xml`?